# Discrete Logarithm Problem in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and using Elliptic curves

Tags: cryptography

I want to learn about the hardness of the DLP in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and using Elliptic curves, and the best attacks against each. I want to be able to compare the hardness of the problem in the two setups. \ Can someone suggest me some useful links, books or papers?

Comment: A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography by Neal Koblitz might be a good place to start.